# How to redo undone actions in Photoshop when other actions have been done

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I went to History in Photoshop and did a couple of undos. After that I wish to redo, however I accidentally did another action so now I can't step forward.

Is there a way to recover my losses? Something like reset back to whatever it was 5 minutes ago would be more than wonderful.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know techie007 is correct but I have a work around.

You will need to create an Action to do this.

Create a New Action. (make sure it is recording when doing the next steps)

Make the first step a "Snapshot" of your document (you want full document snapshot)

Then make your next step a undo.

Now when you undo use the action instead of CTRL-Z

The only downside to this is everytime you undo you make a snapshot. Very RAM intensive if you do a lot of undos.

I made a video of the steps. Hope the video makes sense => [Video Here](http://screencast.com/t/L3cx6RGbA)

Also this [Article](http://www.adobepress.com/articles/article.asp?p=30163&seqNum=9) might help you some.

Hope this helps!

***Update*** I found this out since I posted:

You can try non linear in the history options, but it can be confusing because it works totally different from linear history states. Learn More [Here,](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7497a.html) [Here](http://forensicphotoshop.blogspot.com/2008/04/non-linear-history.html), and [Here](http://www.realgeek.com/forums/non-linear-history-removing-one-history-state-only-391519.html).

Comment: Updated post to include another option I discovered after posting original answer.

Comment: +1 Non-linear history... who knew?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Photoshop's Undo/Redo is a single (indexed) [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_data_structure) structure; so you can't do what you want.

Your best (only?) chance is probably to reload your last save point, from disk.

Bonus: Check out [linked lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) to learn how a stack works. :)

Comment: what do you mean by reload last save point from disk? i didn't have any save points at all. is there an "automatic save point" (like you know microsoft word always have these automatic save points) that i could reload to?

Comment: Reload from last save point is also called "Revert" in the Menu. (File > Revert right under Save for Web & Devices) it is not available if you have never saved the document.